# Cant figure out why my PyTest is giving back an "ID not found" HTTPException?

Tags: pytest

I'm trying to implement an update timer function, but cant figure out why it's not registering that the id does exist in the dictionary (i should also note that all other methods/variables use are correct, with only update_timer() and test_update_timer() being possibly incorrect). Here is my code:

```
//in productivity service

def update_timer(self, timer: PomodoroTimer) -> PomodoroTimer:
        """Modifies one timer in the data store.

        Args:
            timer: Data for a timer with modified values.
        Returns:
            PomodoroTimer: Updated timer.
        Raises:
            HTTPException: Timer does not exist.
        """
        
        global _timers
        initial_timer= _timers[timer.id]
         if initial_timer not in _timers:
            raise HTTPException(
                status_code=404, detail=f"Invalid ID {timer.id}: Timer does not exist."
            )

        initial_timer.name = timer.name
        initial_timer.description = timer.description
        initial_timer.timer_length = timer.timer_length
        initial_timer.break_length = timer.break_length
        
        return initial_timer


// in productivity test

def test_update_timer(productivity_service: ProductivityService):
    timer = PomodoroTimer(
        id=1, name="Sample", description="Description", timer_length=10, break_length=5
    )
initial_timer = productivity_service.create_timer(timer)

timer2 = PomodoroTimer(
    id=1, name="USample", description="UDescription", timer_length=5, break_length=2
)
u_timer = productivity_service.update_timer(timer2)
length = len(productivity_service.get_timers())

assert length == 1
assert u_timer.id ==1
assert u_timer.name == "USample"
assert u_timer.description == "UDescription"
assert u_timer.timer_length == 5
assert u_timer.break_length == 2
```

error received
FAILED productivity_test.py::test_update_timer - fastapi.exceptions.HTTPException

Comment: Why is this tagged as `angular` and `typescript` ?